# How to pass additional parameters (besides arguments) to a function?

Tags: python, function, arguments

I need to write a function (say `fun1`) that has one argument, because it will be used in other function (`fun2`). The latter requires a function with a single argument. However, I need to pass other parameters to function `fun1`. How can I do this in Python without using global variables? Or this is the only way?

Addition:  If it is important, `fun2` is some optimization function from `scipy.optimize`. Below is an example of passing additional parameter `c` to function `fun1` using `global`. In the first call, function `fun2` takes `fun1` as `x+1`, but in the second call, `fun1` is `x+2`. I would like to make similar, but without using `global`. Hopefully, the example clarifies the question. (The example is changed).

```
def fun1(x) :
   global c
   return  x + c

def fun2(f1, x) :
   return  f1(x)

# main program
global c
x0= 1  
c= 1;   y= fun2(fun1, x0);  print(y)    # gives 2
c= 2;   y= fun2(fun1, x0);  print(y)    # gives 3
```

Comment: arguments *are* parameters..

Comment: Please provide some concrete example or code.

Comment: That's better. I had updated my answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Strictly spoken, no. The arguments are the concrete values, the parameters are the "function-side" stuff. So above, the arguments `fun1` and `x0` are assigned to the parameters `f1` and `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, there are quite a number of ways to do what you want and avoid using global variables. Here they are.

Given:

```
x0 = 1
def fun2(f1, x):
    return f1(x)
```

All of these techniques accomplish your goal:

```
#### #0 -- function attributes
def fun1(x):
    return x + fun1.c

fun1.c = 1;  y = fun2(fun1, x0);   print(y)   # --> 2
fun1.c = 2;  y = fun2(fun1, x0);   print(y)   # --> 3

#### #1 -- closure
def fun1(c):
    def wrapper(x):
        return x + c
    return wrapper

y = fun2(fun1(c=1), x0);   print(y)   # --> 2
y = fun2(fun1(c=2), x0);   print(y)   # --> 3

#### #2 -- functools.partial object
from functools import partial

def fun1(x, c):
    return x + c

y = fun2(partial(fun1, c=1), x0);   print(y)   # --> 2
y = fun2(partial(fun1, c=2), x0);   print(y)   # --> 3

#### #3 -- function object (functor)
class Fun1(object):
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.c = c
    def __call__(self, x):
        return x + self.c

y = fun2(Fun1(c=1), x0);   print(y)   # --> 2
y = fun2(Fun1(c=2), x0);   print(y)   # --> 3

#### #4 -- function decorator
def fun1(x, c):
    return x + c

def decorate(c):
    def wrapper(f):
        def wrapped(x):
            return f(x, c)
        return wrapped
    return wrapper

y = fun2(decorate(c=1)(fun1), x0);   print(y)   # --> 2
y = fun2(decorate(c=2)(fun1), x0);   print(y)   # --> 3
```

Note that writing `c=` arguments wasn't always strictly required in the calls -- I just put it in all of the usage examples for consistency and because it makes it clearer how it's being passed.

Comment: You're welcome. That's a good one to use and has the advantage that it's very explicit (self documenting) about what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that that function can be called even without those other parameters suggests, that they are optional and have some default value. So you should use *default arguments*.

```
def fun1(foo, bar='baz'):
    # do something
```

This way you can call function `fun1('hi')` and `bar` will default to `'baz'`. You can also call it `fun1('hi', 15)`.

If they don't have any reasonable default, you can use `None` as the default value instead.

```
def fun1(foo, bar=None):
    if bar is None:
        # `bar` argument was not provided
    else:
        # it was provided
```

Comment: This is not what I ment. In your case, if you call function `fun1` with one argument, then the second argument `bar` can have only the default value (`bar = 'baz'`). I want to change the second argument as well, while calling the function `fun1` with only a single argument.

Comment: @user2320292 you want to pass an argument without passing it? your question is not clear.

Comment: @user2320292 Well, ok, next guess. Maybe you are lookng for [`partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a method in a class.

you define a class, with a method fun1 and an instance variable `c`. it is accessed from anywhere using the `.` notation:

```
class A:
    def fun1(self, x):
        return x + self.c
```

Let's define fun2, for the example:

```
def fun2(f, p):
    return f(p)
```

We can now use `a.c` it like you did with the global varaible `c`:

```
>>> a = A() # create an instance and initialize it
>>>         # "self.c" is undefined yet
>>>
>>> a.c = 1 # "self.c" will be 1
>>> fun2(a.fun1, 1)
2
>>> a.c = 2 # now "self.c" will be 2
>>> fun2(a.fun1, 1) # same arguments, different result
3
```

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) you can learn more about classes.

Comment: Yes, this is how I understand the (badly-worded) question. He wants to modify the behaviour of fun1 in advance of passing it to fun2, and as such it seems that passing an object would be the way to achieve it...

Comment: @Elazar: Thank you for answer. The answer looks a little bit complicated.

Comment: @user2320292 well, it isn't. it's your very function, put into a class. the examples are yours too. I'll clean it up a bit

Comment: @Tom: A variation of putting `fun1()` into class as shown here is to make _it_ a class whose instances are callable -- sometimes called a [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_Python) -- as illustrated in #3 of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the extra parameters with default values:

```
def fun1(param1, param2=None, param3=None):
    ...
```

Then you can call `fun1` from `fun2` like this:

```
def fun2():
    something = fun1(42)
```

And from somewhere else you can call it like this:

```
fun1(42, param2=60)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the decorators to pass it
the very decorators:

```
def jwt_or_redirect(fn):
  @wraps(fn)
  def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  return decorator

def jwt_refresh(fn):
  @wraps(fn)
  def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
    new_kwargs = {'refreshed_jwt': 'xxxxx-xxxxxx'}
    new_kwargs.update(kwargs)
    return fn(*args, **new_kwargs)
  return decorator
```

and the final function:

```
@jwt_or_redirect
@jwt_refresh
def home_page(*args, **kwargs):
  return kwargs['refreched_jwt']
```